# Populating a UIPickerView with data from Sqlite DataBase in IPhone App --

Tags: c#, iphone, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have an **sqlite** database with a table 'BikeInfo'

```
[BikeID, BikeName]
```

Now I want my pickerview to be populated with names of bikes from this database. In .Net it was so easy. But being a complete beginner in MonoTouch, I have got no clue as to how to approach the problem. I did some googling and found out that I have to create some kind of custom class extending from the `UIPickerViewModel` class and override its various methods. But that's about it. I could not find any sample code, tutorial or anything. I have been battling with this for three days now. I am totally confused. So far I have written a function that is fetching the data from the table and returning a list of class objects[that I have written containing the properties BikeName and BikeId]. Maybe I was looking in all the wrong places. But I need to get this done any which ever way.

Any kind of tutorial, or sample code in C# dealing with this target-specific scenario would be helpful to me.

The next objective is to show an alert message showing the corresponding bike id when user touches one particular item. I think we have to define the selected event in that custom class. This much I have picked from the internet.

Thanks.

---

This is what I have done so far. I have created a class containing the properties `BikeID` and `BikeName`.

```
namespace ASTONAPP
{
    public class PickerFacilityTemplate
    {
        public PickerFacilityTemplate ()
        {
        }

        public int BikeID{get; set;}
        public string BikeName{get; set;}
    }
}
```

After that I have written the function in my database handler class which returns a list of class objects of the above class type.

```
public List<PickerFacilityTemplate> FetchFacility()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
    string sql = "select * from BikeInfo order by BikeName";
    this.CreateDBConnection ();
    SqliteDataAdapter sda = new SqliteDataAdapter (sql, sconn);
    sda.Fill (ds);
    List<PickerFacilityTemplate> objfcl=new List<PickerFacilityTemplate>();

    for(int i=0; i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        PickerFacilityTemplate pft=new PickerFacilityTemplate();
        pft.BikeID=Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BikeID"].ToString());
        pft.BikeName=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BikeName"].ToString ();
        objfcl.Add (pft);
    }

    this.CloseDBConnection ();
    return objfcl.ToList ();
}

public class PickerDataModelSource: UIPickerViewModel
{
    public PickerDataModelSource ()
    {
    }

    public PickerDataModelSource (List<PickerFacilityTemplate> lst)
    {
        this.Items=lst;
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

    public List<PickerFacilityTemplate> Items;

    List<PickerFacilityTemplate> _items = new List<PickerFacilityTemplate>();

    public PickerFacilityTemplate SelectedItem 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this._items[this._selectedIndex];                
        } 
    }

    public int _selectedIndex = 0;

    public override int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, int component) 
    {
        return this._items.Count;
    }

    public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component) 
    {
        return items[row].BikeName.ToString();

    }
    public override int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
    {
        this._selectedIndex = row;
        if (this.ValueChanged != null) 
        {
            this.ValueChanged (this, new EventArgs ());
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the class file of the screen where I have the pickerview, I have written,

```
PickerDataModelSource _pickerSource;
```

and in the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
this.Picker.Source=this._pickerSource;
this.Picker.Model=this._pickerSource;
```

But when I run the application, my pickerview is blank. Am I missing something? Where is the error in my logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One example of how to use the picker is in the "kitchen sink" sample - https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop - especially in https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop/PickerViewController.xib.cs

In general, I find that repo essential for lots of mt dev tasks.